# AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android, ionic, cordova, gradle, build

Hola necesito construir el apk de mi aplicación en ionic y me da el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda por favor.‍♀️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo podras encontrar una solucion a tu problema en este post que hablar sobre el error que comentas. -->.
[Resource linking fails on lStar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021225/resource-linking-fails-on-lstar)

Comment: Deberías añadirlo como comentario y no como respuesta.

Comment: lo tendre en cuenta gracias.